# Visual studio crashes while creating team foundation project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014, windows-server-2012-r2

i have one server and few PCs and i wanna configure team foundation server for a small lab ie single server configuration.
i have configured application tier, data tier, build service and collection. but when i want to create a  project inside the collection via team explorer in visual studio, visual studio crashes and restarts.
after that in team foundation server administration console created project appears, but in web source i can't get into collection and projects.
it means that project was not created successfully.
user roles and permissions were allowed as per MSDN guide lines.
i have searched a lot over internet but couldn't find the solution to this problem.
any help and guide lines will be appreciated.

Comment: any info from the Visual Studio crash? are your update versions the same on TFS and VS? or at least VS in front of TFS

Comment: Just a popup appears with "unfortunately visual studio stops working and will restart".
when i cancel that out, sometimes visual studio restarts and sometimes just disappears.

Comment: I am facing same issue...Any update blueBird?